# Join with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have 2 large tables:  Table_A (10 millions rows) and Table_B (7 millions rows) joining using 3 different columns.   My SELECT statement is followed:

```
SELECT Table_A.* , Table_B.*
FROM
   Table_A 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B ON (Table_A.column_a4=Table_B.column_b4   AND  Table_A.column_a5=Table_B.column_b5   AND  Table_A.column_a6=Table_B.column_b6)
WHERE Table_A.column_a1=....
```

I current have the composite Noncluster index on Table_B:  ([column_b4],[column_b5],[column_b6]).   The combination of 3 column in unique.

This join is very slow (taking more than 5 minutes to return the first record).   Please advise for which index on Table_A and Table_B I should create for the LEFT OUTER JOIN to give best performance.  Will it be faster if I create Composite Primary key which consists of 3 columns ?

Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_A
(
  column_a1 [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
  column_a2 [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
  column_a3 [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
  column_a4 [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
  column_a5 [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
  column_a6 [nvarchar] (20) NULL
)
CREATE INDEX IDX_a1a2a3 ON [Table_A] ([column_a1],[column_a2],[column_a3])
INSERT INTO Table_A values('1','1','1','1','1','1')
INSERT INTO Table_A values('2','2','2','2','2','2')
INSERT INTO Table_A values('3','3','3','3','3','3')
INSERT INTO Table_A values('4','4','4','4','4','4')
INSERT INTO Table_A values('5','5','5','5','5','5')

CREATE TABLE Table_B
(
  column_b1 [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
  column_b2 [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
  column_b3 [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
  column_b4 [nvarchar] (20) NOT NULL,
  column_b5 [nvarchar] (20) NOT NULL,
  column_b6 [nvarchar] (20) NOT NULL,
  column_b7 [nvarchar] (20) NULL
)

INSERT INTO Table_B values('11','11','11','1','1','1','11')
INSERT INTO Table_B values('22','22','22','2','2','2','22')
INSERT INTO Table_B values('33','33','33','3','3','3','33')
INSERT INTO Table_B values('44','44','44','4','4','4','44')
INSERT INTO Table_B values('55','55','55','55','55','55','55')

CREATE INDEX IDX_b4b5b6 ON [Table_B] ([column_b4],[column_b5],[column_b6])
```

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? How selective is the `WHERE` on table `A`? It probably isn't using the indexes as they do not cover all columns in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the example. The answer below is based on your example but obviously with more records in the tables behaviour may be different. For the same reason, this may not be the complete solution.

One thing you could improve is to include all columns from Table_B that are returned from the query (are in `SELECT` list) in the index you have `IDX_b4b5b6`. At least in the example, it makes SQL Server to use the index (instead of table scan).

Answer (score 0):

If tables don't already have a primary key, and if those tables are fairly static (not much insert/update going on), consider defining the primary key on those 3 columns together.
ALTER TABLE Table_A ADD CONSTRAINT pk_table_a PRIMARY KEY ([column_a1],[column_a2],[column_a3])